# Getting wrong data from database even if I am fetching something different in laravel api

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, error-handling

Hello guys I am working on a laravel project for making api for passing the database value in json format but the problem is I have a users table in this table 2 ids 1 is primary key and second is business _id I want to get data according to business_id but it's getting data by id please help me how to solve this issue.

Here is my model code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'business';

}
```

Here is my Controller Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\user;

class GetController extends Controller
{
    public function databybusinessid($business _id){
    $users = new user();
    $users = user::find($business _id);
    return response()->json($users);
}
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: $users = user::where('business_id',$business_id)->first();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `user::find($business _id)`

find() method will automatically search by the primary key but none is defined in your model and Eloquent can't decide which one to pick from your table. Therefore, you should explicitly set your primary key in your model by adding the following line.

```
class user extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'business';

    protected $primaryKey = 'business_id';
}
```

If in doubt, you can also fetch database record by a specific column using where

```
 $users = user::where('business_id', '=', $business _id)->get()
```

Laravel documentation about Eloquent ORM
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: thanks dear it;s working but dear there 2 values of business_id of 5 in db but its get only 1

Comment: i mean to say there is 2 users data in db which has business id 5 but its fetch only 1 user data how can we solve this

Comment: Ah so your primary key isn't unique. Just replace `$users = user::where('business_id', '=', $business _id)->first()` by `$users = user::where('business_id', '=', $business _id)->get()`. I'm  also updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much dear you helped me alot it's working like a charm Cheers.:)

Comment: mickael can we chat on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

find() Retrieve a model by its primary key..

So you have to use your code as:

```
$users = user::where('business_id',$business_id)->first();
// Notice first() Retrieve the first model matching the query constraints...
```

Or you can change your primary code in model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'business';
    protected $primaryKey = 'business_id';

}
```

Comment: Why should anyone try this code? What did you change, and why? A great answer always describes the changes, and why they are needed.

Comment: your answer is not complete

Answer (score 0):

find() works only on primary key. you need to use where instead.
or you can define business_id as primary key in your User model.

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'business_id';
```

```php
public function databybusinessid($business _id){
    $users = new user();
    $users = user::where('business_id',$business _id)->first();
    return response()->json($users);
}
```